# Sharepoint site request access email format

Tags: 2007, email, email-templates

Below are the screen shot email samples coming from sharepoint when users request 
access to a certain site. My issue is highlighted in red box.

If the user belong to TECH domain (Figure 1), the request email have the requester’s name beside the logon id(Y699898). But the names of the users who belong to CORP domain are not displayed on the email when they request for access to a site(Figure 2).

**Figure 1**

[image: Figure1]

**Figure 2**

[image: Figure2]

**Figure 3**

[image: Figure3]

Is there a way I can figure this thing out?

My client wanted to make the request uniform in such a way that every time that there will be a request, the name of the user is always beside the logon id.

All formats should look the same as Figure 1. I’ve been looking for solutions on the internet about this issue but found no answer.

I’m hoping that somebody here in stackoverflow could help me solve this issue.

Thank you so much.

**Note:**
TECH is a domain by itself. Likewise for CORP, it is also a domain.
Both domains are connected to exchange server(Outlook).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a profile -> site user info list sync issue. User's not in the site already are not known "completely", i.e. users will be validated based on their user name, but SharePoint won't have their display name available yet (both in the user info list and the user profile service application). These properties get synced to sharepoint at the moment a user is "known" to sharepoint in either the userinfolist or the user profile service application.

Comment: Can you please teach me on how to navigate into profile -> site user info list that you are referring to. Thanks!

Comment: IS it SP2010 or 2007?

Comment: P.S. more info on the user list in a site collection list:http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/06/25/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list.aspx

Comment: P.S. The user info list in a site collection is maintained by Sharepoint itself. You can trigger a sync between user profile service and this list using stsadm -o sync

Comment: It doesn't work. A scheduled timer job was already created to do the sync even before this issue came up. I don't think it has something to do with the profile because as I've checked everything in sharepoint is updated. Thanks for you help :)

Comment: I'm still looking for answers... hoping somebody could help me on this :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer for fixing the problem, but I can offer a little more information which might help... The Request Access page uses a code behind class "RequestAccess" from the assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages

Using reflector, this class contains a method named SendEmail(), which contains this relevant code:

```
string name = this.Context.User.Identity.Name;
// (few removed lines, nothing relevant)
try {
    name += " (" + SPUtility.GetFullNameFromLogin(base.Site, name) + ")";
} catch {
}
```

So whenever you don't see the full name in parens, the SPUtility.GetFullNameFromLogin() method threw an exception.